# How can I see real-time logs when running Rails in Vagrant in detached mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

How can I see real-time logs when running Rails in Vagrant in detached mode, similar to how they would appear if you were just running the rails server locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mount the app directory from the vagrant box on your local machine and tail the log or you could vagrant ssh and tail it

Answer (score 3):

As @bridiver said, you can tail the log files with the `-f` option to watch a real time log.

As an example, if you have a terminal in the app folder wherever the app is running (via ssh or locally, it doesn't matter):

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

(It can be whatever file you're using: development, staging, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ssh connection and directly tail the log:

Like this:

```
vagrant ssh -- -t 'tail -f PATH_TO_LOG/production.log'
```